# ArrayList is nulled when method calls another method?

Tags: java, arraylist, null

I'm trying to debug pickPlayers.  The list "players" is populated successfully after it adds "choice", but when "isPlaying" is called, it's null.

Can anyone see why? I made sure to push the first element picked in so it shouldn't actually *be* a null arraylist; I can't see where it's emptying players once that's done and "isplaying"'s called.

```
public abstract class Game {
protected ArrayList<Player> players;

public Game(String gameName, int numPlayers) {
    this.name = gameName;
    this.totalPlayers = numPlayers;
}

public void pickPlayers(ArrayList<Player> players, int num){
    // rand int between 0 and number of players
    Random generator = new Random(); 
    int rand = generator.nextInt(num) + 0;

    Player choice = null;       
    int i = 0;

    // first player
    for (Player player: players){
        if (i == rand){
            choice = player;
        }
        i++;
    }
    players.add(choice);
    i=1;

    while (i < num){
        rand = generator.nextInt(num) + 0;

        int a=0;
        for (Player player: players){
            if (a == rand){
                choice = player;
                System.out.println(choice.getName());
            }
            a++;
        }

        if (!isPlaying(choice)){
            i++;
            players.add(choice);
            choice.play();
            System.out.println(choice.getName());
        }
    }
}

public boolean isPlaying(Player p){
    return players.contains(p);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are picking random player from the list and adding to the same list. Another thing you are adding the choice outside of your loop.

Also you are never initializing

```
protected ArrayList<Player> players;
```

So it is always null which is an instance variable. When you are calling `pickPlayers()` function `players` is a local variable.

Comment: I was indeed editing the one passed in instead of the one in the state that I was passing in.  My professor had specified in docs that the one passed in and the one in state were the same name (probably a typo?) and once I changed the name and initialized the arraylist, it worked fine.  Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The arrayList that you are modifying is the `Players` that is passed into the `pickPlayers` method and is local to that method.

Either pass this arrayList to `isPLayer` or do not pass in the arrayList to `pickPlayers`

Answer (score 0):

Because they're different objects.  The `players` list being manipulated in `pickPlayers` is an argument, but the one in `isPlaying` is a member of `Game`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the players to `pickPlayers(ArrayList<Player> players, int num)` which is not necessary as the piclPlayers() is in the same class where ArrayList players is present. ArrayList players is instance variable ane it is visible throughout the class. Hence do not pass array list players to the method within the same class.

Answer (score 0):

you have to instantiate ArrayList.
You have to do players = new ArrayList(); inside pickPlayers method. 
After that you can add object otherwise it will show NullPointerException.